# how to search Rows that contain specific characters in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table ( dish )

```
( dish )
id  menu      mi1   mi2   mi3     mi4
1   soup      water egg   salt   (null)
2   sandwich  bread egg   cheese (null)
3   hamberger ham   bread cheese  egg
```

so i want rows that contain 'bread' character

show this result :

```
id  menu      mi1   mi2   mi3     mi4
2   sandwich  bread egg   cheese (null)
3   hamberger ham   bread cheese  egg
```

if I want this result, how to write sql?

i don't want this answer sql

```
SELECT * FROM dish
WHERE mi1 like '%bread%'
OR    mi2 like '%bread%'
OR    mi3 like '%bread%'
OR    mi4 like '%bread%'
```

in sql,
'*' means all columns
then, Is there any characters to mean all rows?

Answer (score 1):

Well, not really, but you can trick it by concating those columns together :

```
SELECT * FROM dish d
WHERE d.mi1 || '-' || d.mi2 || '-' || d.mi3 || '-' || d.mi4 LIKE '%bread%'
```

This way, it will search inside the entire row in one condition ->

```
'soup-water-egg-salt' LIKE '%bread%'
'sandwich-bread-egg-cheese' LIKE '%bread%'
......
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this after apply `CONCAT()`

```
SELECT * 
FROM dish
WHERE  CONCAT(mi1, ' ', mi2, ' ', mi3, ' ', mi4) LIKE '%bread%'
```

Comment: Isn't that the same answer as mine?

Comment: I don't think so. I use the `CONCAT()` function for that,  where you use `||` and add `'-'`

Comment: Using the same query with different function that does exactly the same - is the same.